# column statement not working in Oracle

Tags: oracle, heading

This is something easy - I know it.  Been working for a couple of hours on it, googled it, no luck.  Apologize in advance.

For some reason I can NOT alter the column heading using the column statement in Oracle.

Here is what I am running:

```
column clear;
column PeopleSoftTerms.LName HEADING 'PeopleSoft|Last Name';
SELECT  PeopleSoftTerms.LName,
        PeopleSoftTerms.FName as "PeopleSoft First Name", 
        TO_CHAR(PeopleSoftTerms.termdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD') as "Termination Date", 
        PeopleSoftTerms.ticket as "Maximo Ticket",
        PeopleSoftTerms.LANID as "ID Listed in PeopleSoft",
        Domain.logonid as "Active Directory ID", Domain.DisplayName, Domain.status
FROM PeopleSoftTerms 
     INNER JOIN Domain ON PeopleSoftTerms.LName = Domain.LName AND  
                PeopleSoftTerms.FName = Domain.FName;
```

I am at a loss here.

Comment: did not know that. I just did that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COLUMN commands take the column name only, not the fully qualified column name.

```
core> column event heading "This will work"
core> column v$session.event heading "This will not"
core> select v$session.event from v$session where rownum=1;

This will work
----------------------------------------------------------------
VKTM Logical Idle Wait
```

(This is in SQLPlus.  I do not believe COLUMN is supported at all by SQL Developer.)

Comment: `column` exists in SQL Developer, but only for `new_value`, so you can't set the heading or formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I will try to find another way to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with the "column clear" statement?  If you're trying to clear formatting for a column, then you need to add the field name:

```
column field_name clear
```

If you're just trying to clear the column definitions, then you should reverse and try:

```
clear columns
```

Also, if the "column" statements are a part of the SELECT statement, then you shouldn't need to terminate them with a semi-colon.

```
column PeopleSoftTerms.LName HEADING 'PeopleSoft|Last Name'
SELECT  PeopleSoftTerms.LName,
...
FROM PeopleSoftTerms 
    INNER JOIN Domain ON PeopleSoftTerms.LName = Domain.LName AND  
               PeopleSoftTerms.FName = Domain.FName;
```

Give some of that a try, and see if it helps.

Comment: I removed the semi-colon from the column statement and the clear statement.  No change.

Comment: @DennisKramer just to verify- but you are using SQL+ or SQL Command Line and not some GUI-based tool, right?  The COLUMN statement works fine in SQL+, but I don't think it's supported anywhere else.  If your statement output shows anything like "SQLPlus Command Skipped", then that's your issue.

Comment: I am using the Oracle SQL developer.  I also tried running it from command line also, with the same no result.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the "" on the blank character of last name:

```
column PeopleSoftTerms.LName HEADING 'PeopleSoft|Last" "Name'
```

Comment: Nope, no luck.  That doesn't look like it changed anything